# When talking about Google Stadia, is it incorrect to say "the Stadia" when referring to it?

Tags: grammar, articles

I'm not really well versed in when to use the word "the" in front of something, so I'll just go ahead and say what and why I'm asking.

I was reading a [tweet](https://twitter.com/BandaiNamcoNO/status/1265295697269657600?s=19) where they referred to Google Stadia (a cloud based video game platform, which isn't really an object, but an online service with peripheral devices) using the wording "will be available on the Stadia".

Is this correct or incorrect, even as incorrect as it sounds?  I just figured it might be correct usage since it's a noun.

Comment: "Stadia" is a commercial name - a proper noun - as such, it does not take a determiner.

Comment: People say stupid things in tweets. Platforms drop the article very quickly. (Notwithstanding usage of "The Facebook" by Jesse Eisenberg until the closing minutes of "The Social Network")

Comment: It's a matter of style. Some proper nouns *do* take an article. Consider **the** United States. Or, as in the case of its current president, **the** Donald. There is no universal rule of style, nor is there a style that can be applied identically in every case based purely on syntax.